# free-jqgrid exporting to excel or csv format

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a working model of jqgrid written in java script. Can anyone tell me how to export the grid to excel or csv format?

I didnt't found any plugin for this.

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at **UPDATED** part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28644753/315935) or [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/417) for example. It references the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ovq05x0c/6/

Comment: Thank you.. @Oleg

Comment: Sorry @Nick. I am new to Stackoverflow. Will follow those guidelines... thanks for suggestion.